# C++ How to instantiate abstract parent class constructor from child class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an abstract class, that has two variables. I want to instantiate those variables through the constructor.

Then I want to instantiate those variables from the child classes constructors, but it giving me a casting error?

```
#ifndef Employee_Interface_H
#define Employee_Interface_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee {

private: 
    double salary = 0;
    double sales = 0;
    double bonus = 0;

public:

    Employee(double empSalary, double empSales) {
        salary = empSalary;
        sales = empSales;
    }

    void virtual calculateBonus() = 0;


};

class Staff : public Employee {

public:

    Staff(double empSalary, double empSales) {
        Employee(empSalary,empSales);
    }

    void calculateBonus() {
        //20% of salary
    }


};




#endif
```

`

Comment: You're using the wrong terminology.   A derived class constructor does not instantiate members of a base class.   A derived class constructor *initialises* base classes by calling their constructors, which in turn initialise the members of the base class.    In any event, use an initialiser list in the derived class constructor.  `Staff(double empSalary, double empSales) : Employee(empSalary, empSales) {};`.   Also, use an initialiser list in the base class constructor to initialise members (and bases, if any) of the base class, rather than assigning them in the constructor body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
Staff(double empSalary, double empSales) {
    Employee(empSalary,empSales);
}
```

Use this instead:

```
Staff(double empSalary, double empSales) : 
    Employee(empSalary, empSales)
{
}
```

You have to put the base class constructor call in the derived class constructor's [member-initialization-list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) - after the `:` marker, but before the constructor's body definition.